# How to update and rebuild specific class instance from (dart) Stream?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

Working with Flutter to design a UI that controls nodes over a network. Of course the state of widgets in the Flutter app must match the state of its corresponding network node. All of the network updates come in on Bluetooth. They are decrypted, parsed, and emitted in a dart broadcast `Stream`. The Flutter widgets should subscribe to the stream and reflect the updates (by rebuilding in some new state i.e. color).

I can't seem to find a good solution for updating individual widgets from the stream. The class instance for the widgets are built with `this.address`, `this.name`, etc. which correspond to the network address, name, etc. of each node. Ideally each instanced widget will be listening to the stream, and rebuild IFF the `address` it holds matches the `address` field from the stream values as they are listened to.

I have been working with provider/consumer because the bluetooth package depends on it and it seems like a useful tool, and was thinking it would be part of the solution but can't seem to make it work so far. Looking for any and all guidance on how to architect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)!

> Widget that builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Stream. Widget rebuilding is scheduled by each interaction, using State.setState, but is otherwise decoupled from the timing of the stream.

Check out this video on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/MkKEWHfy99Y)

```dart
StreamBuilder(
          stream:  , // some stream...
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
            List<Widget> children;
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              // Handle error
            } else {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  // Not currently connected to any asynchronous computation.

                  break;
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  // Connected to an asynchronous computation and awaiting interaction.

                  break;
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  // Connected to an active asynchronous computation.

                  break;
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  // Connected to a terminated asynchronous computation.

                  break;
              }
            }

            // Default action
        ),
```

Comment: This looks like it has potential. is it conceivable to use a conditional statement based on snapshot.data to prevent the widget (i.e. keep the existing widget) from rebuilding? I'm trying to have the widget only rebuild when the stream data contains a data field that matches a stored data field in a given instance (an address).

Comment: Yep. Definitely. The `builder` parameter accepts a function which is called every time the stream has a new value. But if your stream emits values at a high frequency, then it might be a bit costly to add too many conditions. `StreamBuilder` is one of the best solutions to manage UI based on the value provided by the stream. The flutter team recommends it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am making progress with this, and per your last comment I was weighing the idea of breaking the main stream into sub streams, one for each widget that should be rebuilt as the incoming data dictates. So going down that path I think it makes the most sense to create a new stream, add a listener (the widget to rebuild) emit the new value, then close the stream. This would occur every time a data event comes on the main steam. Does this make sense versus the original plan to broadcast the main stream to all widgets and let each widget decide if the data event applies to it?

Comment: @MatthewNeber that's a great idea. The benefit of flutter is that you can split your UI into many widgets. So, try to extract the part of the UI which will be updated into its own widget and only wrap them in `StreamBuilder`s. This decreases the chances of jank and keeps the battery usage in check. Adding a listener to the main widget may have side effects; especially if you widgets which use animations, clips, shaders and need not be rebuilt

Comment: Also, `StreamBuilder` takes care of everything. Adding a subscription to the stream, and then disposition as well

Comment: `StreamBuilder` is definitely a good solution. I have it working with some dummy data. I used Provider.of to pass in the stream to the builder (saves the headache of passing the StreamController object through children). Not** StreamProvider as this emits the raw stream data. I did look into a way of creating a custom Consumer class to work with StreamProvider and optimize the widget rebuilds but at this point it is a little more work than worth it